# How to programmatically trigger Mouse & Keyboard events for Windows, Linux & Mac

Tags: python-3.x, mouseevent, cross-platform, keyboard-events, xdotool

**Hi,**

I'm curious about developing a small application to achieve programmatically trigger Mouse & Keyboard events for Windows, Linux & Mac desktops with a single code base.

For that, I learned a few things with **xdotool** I wrote a simple python which works fine in both Linux & OSX But not in windows.

Is there any option to make it work with Windows also? Or please suggest to me if there are any other ways(Programming, Libraries, or Frameworks) to achieve this.

**Example:**

1. Keyboard Events: Cut, Copy, Paste, Atl Tab, Caps Lock, Search in the editor, etc.
2. Mouse: Left & Right Clicks, Scroll, Move left(Eg.10 pixel), right, top, etc.

Written Python code works for the Linux & Mac.

```
import os

os.system('xdotool key "Alt+Tab" &')
#os.system('shutdown /s /t 1 &')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try keyboard library: https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

It works with Linux, Windows and should work with OSX. This library should do the job.